# jQuery $('select-element').val() not reliable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I am working with a `<select />` element and I have to determine the value of the selected option. I have used jQuery for a while and I thought I knew how to do this before, but I am encountering unexpected results when **no option** is selected. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webuser7/ffdotsav/1/) that hopefully illustrates my difficulty (whenever the first/guiding option is selected).

I tried the following:

```
$(this).val();
$(this).find('option:selected').val();
$(this).find(':selected').val();
```

This line (below) practically ostracizes jQuery's priceless `.val()` function, but appears to reliably give me what I am looking for:

```
$(this).find('option:selected').attr('value')
```

Is there a reliable way to determine if the user has **not** selected a real option?!

**Note:** I have a strong liking for jQuery's `.val()` function, so finally ended up doing this:

```
$(this).find('option:selected[value]').val()
```

Comment: You could either put an arbitrary value in the first option, or check if val is undefined.

Comment: I don't think you mean *ostracizes*. Also, why not just look at the index of the selected option element?

Comment: what does `unexpected results` mean? if no value attribute  on option value will be it's text. Please define problem with more specifics

Comment: @charlietfl that is what I observed and that is a misleading implementation, because `.val()` should refer to a **value**, IMO. I have a huge respect and admiration for jQuery, so not trying to dispute something that may be working for countless others.

Comment: Your jsFiddle is working perfectly for me.  It's correctly showing `"undefined"` for `attr('value')` because the `value` attribute is missing for this particular `option`.

Comment: Has nothing to do with jQuery, that's part of html spec and is determined by browser itself, not jQuery

Comment: @WebUser What you think it should work like has not necessarily something to do with how it actually works like. In this case, jQuery does the correct thing and your expectations are wrong.

Comment: @j08691 yeah, *ostracizes* is probably unsuitable here, but I just used it because it renders the meaning of `.val()` meaningless and ended up not being an option if I went the way of `.attr('value')`!

Comment: No, it means your perception and opinion need to be adjusted to the way the browsers manage the DOM per specifications. Chalk it up to learning experience and move on

Comment: @charlietfl whoah, go easy on me, please! :-) But thanks for your comments too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to add empty `value` property?

```
<option value="">Select an item</option>
```

In this case you can check if value is not empty and this will mean that user hasn't selected real option.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffdotsav/2/)

Comment: For this particular use case, I want to avoid adding any attribute if it does not have a value. Otherwise, that is what I generally do and perhaps why I never encountered this error before.

Comment: The value of an option that has no `value` attribute is its string value. That is standardized. If you don't want that, override the string value with an empty `value` attribute.

Comment: @Tomalak so what's the problem to check if `$(this).find('option:selected').attr('value')` is equal to `undefined`?

Comment: @Tomalak I did not realize the HTML spec stated that. If so, I have to make peace with jQuery's implementation! :-)